# How to update a locale and timezone on a static image that isn't running

Tags: locale, timezone

I am building an Ubuntu static image (for flashing to a USB) where I want to preset the timezone and locale in that image so that it is already set when the image boots.  It appears the only way to change these values is via the commands `timedatectl` and `update-local`, respectively.  But these can only be used on a running system not on an image.

I did try updating the image's `/etc/timezone` and `/etc/default/locale` directly but when it boots the system still doesn't know about the updated values -- so it is apparently not even looking at them.  It still requires setting these values via the commands.

I've read about `systemd-firstboot` but it isn't clear how that might be used in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

How are you building the image, and why can't you set the timezone at buildtime?

e.g., are you making a docker image?  In which case just put `RUN dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` (or `RUN tzconfig`, or `RUN timedatectl`, or whatever you're distro requires) in your Dockerfile

Comment: It is not docker.  This is a standard image being built for flashing to a USB.  Since it is a static image that is not running, the standard commands don't work because systemd is not running.  Some items I can update but this hasn't worked with updating /etc/timezone or /etc/default/locale. I updated the original question.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  I don't know exactly what files those commands update, so can't offer a proper answer.  I do have a way forward, but it's not the best answer - it's barely even a right one.  If you want to see what changes a command makes to the filesystem, docker layers are simply tarballs of the changes the respective command made.  You could put RUN timdatectl in a one-line dockerfile, build it, and then tar -zxf the layer it creates to see what changes were made.  Not nice, but something to try.  I'd be keen to know the answer myself.